# Reading in C line by line and storing in an array

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to read in file names from a list of files and storing these names in filenames[] array.

```
const int NUMBER_OF_FILES = 100;//here please define number of files listed in 
char* filenames [NUMBER_OF_FILES];//will contain all the file names in the list provided in List_of_input_files.txt

int counter=0;
FILE *inputfilelist = fopen("List_of_input_files.txt", "r");
char line[256];


  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), inputfilelist)){

    filenames[counter]=line;    
    printf("%s counter: %d\n\n\n", filenames[counter], counter);
    counter++;
  }


//**************PROBLEM IS HERE***************

printf("\n\n\n\n%s Counter: 3 ", filenames[2]);// this is only to test what is inside this filename stored

fclose(inputfilelist);
```

The output is:

```
File1.txt
 counter: 0


File2.gif
 counter: 1


File3.bat
 counter: 2


File4.xml
 counter: 3


File5
 counter: 4


File6.7z
 counter: 5


File7.xlsx
 counter: 6






File7.xlsx
  Counter : 3
```

The problem is the last one file Name should be File3.bat but somehow it is not.
It always Shows the last file in line i.e. File7.xlsx.

Maybe it is a silly mistake I am doing and not seeing it clearly or somethingelse. I am new to c so I am not sure. Please help!

It has been improved and the requested things have been added.

Comment: When positing code, you should review your indentation for consitancy and readability.

Comment: Post the contents of `List_of_input_files.txt`

Comment: You are reading all data into the same array thereby overwriting what was previously in there. Probably not what you've meant to do.

Comment: It is the same Array but each filenames[0] or filenames[1] should contain a unique filename. Please help

Comment: @Arc676  'List_of_input_files.txt' only has seven file names displayed in the output

Comment: @ITguy - **post the input file**. Also, each time you fread into the linebuffer, you overwrite what was there before. `Filenames` is an array of pointers. All of these pointers point to lineBuffer. Again, the data that lineBuffer points to is changed with each call to fread. You should make a copy of each string after reading from file using the `strdup` function. Set the elements of the array to be the return value of this function called on the lineBuffer each time. ;)

Comment: @Caleb - actually, they're the newlines from the input file. Print the string out surrounded by single quotes and it immediately becomes apparent that's where those \n's come from.

Comment: @Caleb: `fgets` will store the trailing newline to the target buffer if there's room, so the newlines are coming from the input file.

Comment: @JohnBode Right -- that's essentially what enhzflep pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
filenames[counter]=line;
```

doesn't do what you want; it copies the *address* of the `line` buffer to `filenames[counter]`; all of your `filenames[i]` point to `line`, so when you print `filenames[2]`, it will print out the last thing read into `line`.

If you want to copy the *contents* of `line` to `filenames[counter]`, you'll need to allocate memory to hold the copy using `malloc` or `calloc` and then copy the contents using `strcpy` (or use `strdup` if you have it available):

```
filenames[counter] = malloc( strlen( line ) + 1 );
if ( filenames[counter] )
  strcpy( filenames[counter], line );
```

or

```
filenames[counter] = strdup( line ); // if you have strdup available;
                                     // it's not a standard function
```

You'll need to `free` each `filenames[i]` when you're done.

Alternately, you can declare the `filenames` array as a 2D array of `char`:

```
char filenames[NUMBER_OF_FILES][256];
```

and read directly into the array:

```
fgets(filenames[counter], sizeof(filenames[counter]), inputfilelist))
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to allocate memory to store multiple filenames.

```
const int NUMBER_OF_FILES = 100;//here please define number of files listed in
const int MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE = 50;
char filenames[NUMBER_OF_FILES][MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE];//will contain all the file names in the list provided in List_of_input_files.txt

int counter=0;
FILE *inputfilelist = fopen("List_of_input_files.txt", "r");
char line[256];


  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), inputfilelist))
  {

    //filenames[counter]=line;
    strcpy(filenames[counter],line);
    printf("%s counter: %d\n\n", filenames[counter], counter);
    counter++;
  }


//**************PROBLEM IS HERE***************

printf("\n\n\n%s Counter: 3 ", filenames[2]);// this is only to test what is inside this filename stored

fclose(inputfilelist);
```

Comment: Why read lines into 256 sized buffer only to copy them into a size 50 one?  Suggest `char line[MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE];`.  May also want to strip the trailing `'\n'` after `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux, I generally don't put all the the error checks in the answers I provide. I believe in giving minimal working code. I leave them as an exercise to the person who asked the question. BTW, I agree, there are lot of issues left in the code. If I've to use it for my personal use, I'll not use as is :)